# How to write HIbernate Criteria for a query with subselects

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, hibernate-criteria

I have two entities **Issue** and **Issue_Tracker**. I am using hibernate 3.6 and one to many association.

**Issue.java**

```
public class Issue implements Serializable {
        private Integer issue_id;
        private String  issue_description;
        private Date issue_raised_date;
        private Set<Issue_Tracker> issueTracker = new HashSet<Issue_Tracker>(0);

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="issue_id")
        public Set<Issue_Tracker> getIssueTracker() {
        return issueTracker;
}

public void setIssueTracker(Set<Issue_Tracker> issueTracker) {
    this.issueTracker = issueTracker;
```

**Issue_Tracker.java**

```
public class Issue_Tracker implements Serializable
{  
     private Integer   issue_id;
     private String    tracker_status;
     private Timestamp tracked_time;**
```

And this is the **sql query**, how to achieve this using criteria

```
SELECT i.issue_id, i.issue_description,
       it.tracker_status, it.tracked_time
FROM issues i 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT it.issue_id, it.tracker_status, it.tracked_time 
            FROM issue_tracker it 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT issue_id, MAX(tracked_time) tracked_time 
                        FROM issue_tracker GROUP BY issue_id
                       ) A ON it.issue_id = A.issue_id AND it.tracked_time = A.tracked_time 
          ) it ON i.issue_id = it.issue_id 
WHERE i.status = "Escalate To";
```

Comment: Why do you want criteria? You already have SQL query, just use it.

Comment: thanks ,that is  what i have done, but is it possible to achieve this using criteria, As i am @beginner level for criteria, so so

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you change the confusing name of Issue.issueTracker to Issue.issueTrackers since it is a Set. It makes things easier to read when you are querying. But whatever.

In Criteria API I do not think you can directly translate this SQL. You are better off writing a description of what result set you want. Do you want *the last tracked time for all issues with "Escalate To" status*? If so this should be close to what you want.

```
    DetachedCriteria inner = DetachedCriteria.forClass(IssueTracker.class, "inner")
        .setProjection(Projections.max("inner.tracked_time"));

    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Issue.class, "issue");

    // Add the join with an ON clause (I am not sure why you need the LEFT JOIN)
    crit.createAlias("issueTracker", "it", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN, 
        Subqueries.eqProperty("it.tracked_time", inner));

    // Specify the SELECT fields
    crit.setProjections(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property("issue_id"))
            // etc
            .add(Projections.property("it.tracked_time"));

    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("status", "Escalate To");

    List<Object[]> rows = crit.list();
```